# How to convert .pb file to .h5. (Tensorflow model to keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've retrained my model using `tensorflow` and now want to use `keras` to avoid session stuffs.  How can I convert `.pb` file to `.h5`

Comment: Does https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8026 help you?

Answer (score 4):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import save_model, Sequential

model_path = r"c:\temp\model.pb"

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

save_model(model,model_path + r"\new_model.h5", save_format='h5')
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: @BDL generally I tend to agree, but in this specific case I am pretty sure the code is self explanatory. i.e. "tf.keras.models.load_model" will load a tensor flow model, while save_model with argument save_format='h5' will, hmmm, save it as an h5 keras file.

Comment: @nivpeled I tried same code and got AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute '_is_graph_network'

Comment: I get OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: saved_model_dir/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb} error

Comment: AttributeError: 'AutoTrackable' object has no attribute '_is_graph_network' .I am also getting this error, have you solved?

Comment: model_path should be the path of directory not path of file so should use like "c:\temp"

Answer (score 1):

I found this link useful: https://backstreetcoder.com/convert-tensorflow-pb-model-to-keras-h5-model/

Apparently, you need to use the enclosing directory name and not the .pb filename when loading the model initially. This solves the error:

```
SavedModel file does not exist at: saved_model_dir/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```